# React native permissions always return unavailable on ios simulators

Tags: react-native, react-native-permissions

I have an application that uses `react-native-permissions`. Basically I have a modal regarding location on my `App.js` and it will display as long as the user didn't select the "Always allow" option in device settings. It works well on android however modal is always showing in ios simulators knowing that I already selected the "Always allow".

Here's my code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    checkLocationPermission();
  }, []);

  const checkLocationPermission = async () => {
    const permission =
      Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
        : PERMISSIONS.IOS.LOCATION_ALWAYS;

    const permissionStatus = await check(permission);

    if (
      permissionStatus !== RESULTS.GRANTED &&
      permissionStatus !== RESULTS.BLOCKED
    ) {
      setCustomModal(true);
    }
```

I tried to `console.log(permissionStatus)` and found out that it returns `unavailable`

Note that I already the following in my `info.plist`

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

And in my `podfile`

```
permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "#{permissions_path}/LocationWhenInUse"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I manage to fix the issue by adding these command in my `Podfile`

```
pod 'Permission-LocationWhenInUse', :path => "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationWhenInUse/Permission-LocationWhenInUse.podspec" 
pod 'Permission-LocationAlways', :path => "../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios/LocationAlways/Permission-LocationAlways.podspec"
```

**NOTE:** `.podspec` file sometimes have different filename depends on the version so make sure to check in `node_modules` to avoid `pod install` issue.

After applying the code changes I run these commands.

```
rm -rf /Library/Caches/CocoaPods && rm -rf Pods && rm -rf /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/* && cd ios && pod cache clean --all && pod deintegrate && pod setup && pod install --verbose && cd ..
```

And then re run my project.

Comment: Wouldn't this break your app if RNP authors change the path? Maybe it won't happen, but would you bet $10,000,000 that it won't? That's what major companies spend on their apps. Meanwhile, I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: Running the commands after setting up the permissions is the key. Additionally, I have removed the app from the device and run it again. Thanks, Euph!